# can't update .po file in Django 1.8.8

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm new to Django and now I am practicing Django Internationalization, intending to show my webpages in Chinese, however:

Whatever changes I've made into the **django.po** file, and used `compilemesseages` to generate the **.mo** file, the pages still returned the previous translations, even if I deleted the .po file to generate a new one.
Did I miss something? If so, please tell me, thank you :)

This is my settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-CN'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ('English')),
    ('zh_CN', ('中文简体')),
    ('zh-hant', ('中文繁體')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

also I've added the `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'`into `settings.py`, just like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

what I was test is this function in `views.py`:

```
def test1_view(request): 
    n = 2
    weekdays = [_('Monday'), _('Tuesday'), _('Wednesday'), _('Thursday'), _('Friday'), _('Saturday'), 
_('Sunday')] 
    return HttpResponse(weekdays[n])
```

the django.po file generated at /locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po, and i'm sure i had delete the `#,fuzzy`:

```
#: testdeploy/views.py:64
msgid "Monday"
msgstr "一"

#: testdeploy/views.py:64
msgid "Tuesday"
msgstr "二"

#: testdeploy/views.py:64
msgid "Wednesday"
msgstr "三"

#: testdeploy/views.py:64
msgid "Thursday"
msgstr "四"

#: testdeploy/views.py:64
msgid "Friday"
msgstr "五"

#: testdeploy/views.py:64
msgid "Saturday"
msgstr "六"

#: testdeploy/views.py:65
msgid "Sunday"
msgstr "七"
```

then I used the `$ python manage.py compilemessages` and the .mo file generated, but when I restarted the server, the page was still as the same as the first time I modified the `.po` file: it just showed "星期三" instead of "三".

I'm really confused about this, are there some cookies that I should empty to ensure the changes could work? TOT

PS: My django version is **1.8.8**

Comment: You need to change language to see translations. To check it, remove `('en', ('English')),` line and check result? Does it works?

Comment: @Emin Mastizada hmm, I'm afraid not. It looks so weird! Even though I removed the .po and .mo files, it could still return the previous translations I'd wrote...

Comment: Did you restarted app after changing something? Locales are loaded only when you restart the app (stop and start runserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 3 days , I finally solved this problem by writing emails for help. Actually this problem seemed to be caused by some specific languages settings, such as Chinese:
I changed my `settings.py`:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ('English')),
    ('zh-CN', ('中文简体')),
    ('zh-TW', ('中文繁體')),
)
```

which used '-' instead of '_', however still used

```
$ python manage.py makemessages -l zh_CN
```

to generate the django.po（where the '_' was still the same）.

@Emin Mastizada， thank you all the same :)